# C language: how float got truncated when being cast to char

Tags: c, floating-point

```
float a=6.6;
char d=(char)a;
char *c=(char*)&a;
printf("%A\n",a);
printf("%d \n",d);
printf("%d\n",*c);
```

the result is:

```
0X1.A66666P+2
6 
51
```

---

I don't understand why the second cast prints 51.

Comment: See the answer with the highest vote in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270637/typecasting-from-int-float-char-double).

Answer (score 2):

a 'float' number is just a numeric representation of the decimal number on 32 bits denominated IEEE 754, which uses 1 bit for sign, 8 bit for exponent ( ^2) and 23 bits for the mantissa (24 if you count the implicit 1)

so, your float number 6.6 is actually 32 bits with the value `01000000110100110011001100110011` , or the same number in hexadecimal, `40 d3 33 33`

when you make the cast char `*c=(char*)&a;` you are actually making c point to the first byte of the 32 bits of the float number, you are pointing to the lowest `0x33` which as you remember, hex 33 = 51 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

This result is implementation-defined. It depends on several factors, such as the endianness of the system and the format used to represent floating point numbers.

Assuming that your system uses IEEE-754 numbers, hex representation of `float` is `0x40D33333` ([calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=054046054)).

The initial byte of that float is either `0x40` or `0x33`, depending on the endianness. It appears that on your system the bytes are stored in reverse order, so the initial byte is `0x33`, or 51 in decimal. This is what gets printed when you re-interpret the bytes of your `float` as a single `char` value by casting the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

6.6 is stored in IEEE 754 representation (`0x40d33333`) in memory.
On a little endian system your are working on, `&a[0]` is the least significant byte `0x33` = `51d`.

When you make reference to a **variable** (as in the second cast), C is interpreting the IEEE 754 as 6.6 in float.
Dereferencing a **pointer** (`*((char*)&a)`) exposes the underlying memory representation to you.
That is a bless (or cursing for newbies) of C language.

See:
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IEEE_floating_point
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 1):

"char *c = (char*) &a" casts the address of variable a to char pointer, not the content it self. When you dereference a character pointer, the program does not know the type that the pointer point to, so it takes one byte at the memory location and treats it as char type.

Perhaps, it is easier to understand if you use integer instead:

```
int a = 0x01020304;
char *c = (char*) &a;
printf("%d\n", *c);
```

The above statement should print out either 1 or 4, depending on the "endianness" of the system. (On Windows, it will print out 04).